# How to get the time duration of a video on electron?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, electron

I'm trying to get the time duration of video with document.getElementById('my_video').duration in electron. I open the file using the folowing code:

```
dialog.showOpenDialog(
    { properties: [ 'openFile' ] }, function ( filename ) {
        //Set the src of tag video html5
        var video = document.getElementById('video').setAttribute('src', filename.toString())
    }
);
```

But I can only calculate when the downloaded video is already in my file folder in any folder on my computer, I get "Infinity". Would anyone can help me?